# Can hosts file rewrites be realized in Apache conf?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have a line in /etc/hosts to rewrite something to localhost:

```
127.0.0.1   foo.bar
```

Can the equivalent be done without modifying the hosts file, somehow with an Apache rewrite or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. They are for different purposes and work on a completely different protocol.

- The `/etc/hosts` affects *client* behavior on which IP it should resolve instead of using DNS.
- The Apache virtualhost configuration defines what the *server* does with the HTTP `Host:` header.
- The Apache [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) does URL rewriting after the connection is already established & the correct virtualhost is decided. It can rewrite within filesystem or perform an external *redirect*.